# Force gensim's word2vec vectors to be positive?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

Is there any way in gensim that i can force the learned vectors in word2vec to be all positive? (all the elements of vector be positive). i am working on a different task that needs these vectors to be positive ( the reason is really complicated so don't ask why )

so what is the easiest way for me to force gensim to learn positive vectors?

Comment: I am not sure it makes sense - think about 2-dimensional vectors - if you restrict your vectors to positive values then they are all located in the 1st quadrant. Seems very restrictive. What if you want two vectors to point int the opposite directions - you can't do that. Or you need a vector that is orthogonal to another vector - can't do that either.

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov Can't I somehow "push" them to the positive values? there has to be a way to achieve this without losing information

Comment: Nope. Have you considered my examples? You had two orthogonal vectors (two totally unrelated words), after your change they can't be orthogonal. Information lost.

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov but how about if we "push" all the vectors after they are learned? for example lets say we have two vectors : [ -1 , -2 ] , [ 2,3],  after the push they are : [ 0 , 0] , [ 3 , 5].  is there information loss in this? because the distance is still the same.

Comment: What's the distance before and after in your opinion? Especially with the [0,0] vector which is of length 0 and can't be used to compute cosine similarity at all? In any case, 1 example can't prove that it's possible overall. You still haven't answered how you can have 2 all positive orthogonal vectors?

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov yeah now that I'm thinking about it more, it seems like there will be a lot of information loss no matter what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in feature of Gensim that would allow this extra constraint/regularization to be applied during training.

You should probably try to explain your 'really complicated' reason for this idosyncratic request. There might be a better way to achieve the real end-goal, rather than shoehorning vectors that are typically bushy-and-balanced around the origin into a non-negative representation.

Notably, a paper called '[All-but-the-Top: Simple and Effective Postprocessing for Word Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01417)' has suggested word-vectors can be improved by postprocessing to ensure they are *more* balanced around the origin, rather than less (as seems a reliable side-effect of typical negative-sampling configurations).

If you're still interested to experiment in the opposite direction – transforming usual word2vec word-vectors into a representation where all dimensions are positive – I can think of a number of trivial, superficial ways to achieve that. I have no idea whether they'd actually preserve, or ruin, beneficial properties in the vectors – but you could try them, and see. For example:

- You could try simply setting all negative dimensions to 0.0 - truncation. (Loses lots of info but might give a quick indication if a dirt-simple experiment gives you any of the benefits you seek.)
- You could find the largest negative dimension that appears anywhere in any of the vectors, then add its absolute value to all other dimensions. Voila! No vector dimension is now lower than 0.0. (You could also try this in a per-dimension manner - only correct dimension #0 with the lowest dimension #0 value. Or, try other re-scalings of each dimension such that the previously-highly-negative values are 0.0, and the previous-highly-positive values stay where they are or only shift a little.)
- You could try turning every dimension in the original word-vectors into two dimensions in a transformed set: one that's the original positive value, or 0.0 if it was negative, and a 2nd dimension that's the absolute value of the original negative value, or 0.0 if it was positive. (Or similarly: one dimension that's the absolute-value of the original value, and one dimension that's 0.0 or 1.0 depending on whether original value was negative or positive.)

There are probably other more-sophisticated factorization/decompositions for re-representing the full set of word-vectors in a transformed array with only non-negative individual values, but I don't know them offhand, other than to think it might be worth searching for them.

And, whether any of these transformations work for your next steps, who knows? But it might be worth trying. (And if any of these offer surprisingly good results, it'd be great to hear in a followup comment!)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, the reason I'm doing this is because of this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06108.pdf, it needs all the inputs to the binary classification model to be positive, and it sets the weights of model to be all positive so it makes the model more robust and harder to evade by adding benign features (class number 0), the problem with w2v is some of the vectors could have negative members, which will make the negative weights useless.

Comment: Interesting! Without having read/understood that paper beyond the abstract, if its summary is accurate that it is simply the non-negativeness (& not other things like sparsity/interpretability/etc) of each dimension that helps, any of the simple transforms I suggested might be helpful.

Comment: More generally for resistance to adversely-chosen examples, I wonder if other transforms of the final vectors (any scaling/rotation/etc), or parallel alternate trainings of the word-vectors (eg concatenating final word-vecs from models of different dimensions/other-metaparameters) might also help - especially against attackers who'd otherwise know exactly the word-vec set, or training parameters. (It'd also be interesting if the transforms suggested in that `all-but-the-top` paper have any effect on the susceptibility to adversarial examples.)